# jquery ajax return value and done function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this little example on jquery documentation page. I always tried returning value from ajax function and I was always told that there is some problem of sync and async thing and I can't return value out of $.ajax function without making it async.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

In the example above, on what this done function is applied(whats being used as $(this) in example).

one more thing, as the ajax function can't set global variables, can't the be set in this done too? cant I return value out of done function either?

Comment: `this` is the `body` element.

Comment: you mean the context thing will come as $(this)?

Comment: You probably meant *"I can't return a value out of `$.ajax` function without making it **sync**."*

Comment: yeah thats exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what this done function is applied

`$.ajax` returns a [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (see first section after the configuration parameter description) wich implements the [promise interface](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and allows you to add callbacks and get notified of changes of the Ajax call.

> whats being used as $(this) in example

Inside the callbacks for `$.ajax`, `this` refers to the object `context` refers to in the configuration or the jqXHR instance if `context` was not set. In this case it refers to `document.body`:

> **context:** This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to `$.ajax`).

This and more is all explained in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

---

> as the ajax function can't set global variables

That is not correct, any function can set global variables. The problem with asynchronous functions is that you are likely *accessing* the variable *before* it was set.

> can't the be set in this done too

See above

> cant I return value out of done function either

You can return a value (as in putting a `return` statement inside the callback), but you cannot return it to *your* code, since jQuery is calling the callback *internally* and just ignoring the return value.

Comment: so (done) also wont be able to change a value of my already set global variable?

Comment: @Sourabh: As I said, any function can change the value of global variables. **Setting** is not the problem, **accessing** is. Since you don't know *when* the callback is executed and the variable is set, you don't know when to access it.